# How to use sendirect() method to pass search query from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to do the search query in servlet and load it to jsp table's raw.

```
    Connection dbCon = null;
    PreparedStatement state = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String insert_sql = "insert into item(name,unit_price) values(?,?)";
    String search_sql = "select * from item";
    try {
        String item_name = request.getParameter("item_name");
        String up = request.getParameter("unit_price");
        try {
            dbCon = DB.JDBC.getConnection();
            state = dbCon.prepareStatement(insert_sql);
            dbCon.setAutoCommit(false);

            state.setString(1, item_name);
            state.setString(2, up);
            state.executeUpdate();

            dbCon.commit();


            rs = state.executeQuery(search_sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String item_id = rs.getString("item_id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String unit_price = rs.getString("unit_price");
                String qty = rs.getString("qty");
                try {
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?item_id=" + item_id + "&name=" + name + "&unit_price=" + unit_price + "&qty" + qty);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?msg=New Item added successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dbCon.rollback();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Insertion is working fine. Also first record of the search also load in search bar of the browser. And this is my jsp query.

```
               <tr>
                    <td><% request.getParameter("item_id");%></td>
                    <td><% request.getParameter("name");%></td>
                    <td><% request.getParameter("unit_price");%></td>
                    <td><% request.getParameter("qty");%></td>
                </tr>
```

I think problem is in parameter passing. I'm little bit novel to jsp. So don't know all syntax. Please help me.

**Edit 1**
I changed jsp like this.

```
                <%
                    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) session.getAttribute("rs");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String item_id = rs.getString("item_id");
                        String name = rs.getString("name");
                        String unit_price = rs.getString("unit_price");
                        String qty = rs.getString("qty");
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=item_id%></td>
                    <td><%=name%></td>
                    <td><%=unit_price%></td>
                    <td><%=qty%></td>
                </tr>
                <%}%>
            </tbody>
```

Also servlet like this

```
   rs = state.executeQuery(search_sql);

                session.setAttribute("rs", rs);
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); //redirect to jsp without any params
```

Now I'm having org.apache.jasper.JasperException in the line where while start in jsp.

This is the error. 
[image]

Comment: You need to forward not send redirect. Add your object into response like here rs.

Comment: @Naman can please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the expression tag which is used as follows:

```
<td><%=request.getParameter("item_id")%></td>
<td><%=request.getParameter("name")%></td>
<td><%=request.getParameter("unit_price")%></td>
<td><%=request.getParameter("qty")%></td>
```

Update:

Save the resultset object session in your servlet like this:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    rs = state.executeQuery(search_sql);  //after executing the query just write these two lines instead of while loop
   HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>(); //change here
ArrayList<String> ls=null; //change here
int i=0;
    while (rs.next()) {
                ls=new ArrayList<String>(); //change here
                ls.add(rs.getString("item_id"));
                ls.add(rs.getString("name"));
                ls.add(rs.getString("unit_price"));
                ls.add(rs.getString("qty"));
                hm.put("row"+(++i), ls);
            }
    session.setAttribute("hm",hm);
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); //redirect to jsp without any params
```

and on your jsp:

```
<%
HashMap hm=(HashMap)session.getAttribute("hm");
Set<String> keyset=hm.keySet();
Iterator itr = keyset.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String key = itr.next();
    ArrayList<String> ls = (ArrayList)hm.get(key); 
    String item_id = ls.get(0);
    String name = ls.get(1);
    String unit_price = ls.get(2);
    String qty = ls.get(3);
    %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=item_id%></td>
      <td><%=name%></td>
      <td><%=unit_price%></td>
      <td><%=qty%></td>
    </tr>
<%
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake add this javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session = request.getSession();

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake check the answer you have to remove while loop in your servlet and just store the resultset object in session and whatever exeption you are getting tell in detail..

Comment: Have you removed the while loop like I said?? @DiliniRathnayake

Comment: I removed the while loop in the servlet

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake we cannot put the resultset object in session because it gets closed when the connection gets closed hence we got rs=null on jsp. so i have used some collection classes .. see  the changes in my answer and try to implement. if any error comes ..tell me ..

Comment: Thank u for your support but compiler says this hash map and array like concatenation is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74695/discussion-between-brijesh-bhatt-and-dilini-rathnayake).

Comment: some changes i have done in my answer you can see
declare ArrayList<String> inplace of ArrayList<Object> and List<Object>everywhere

Comment: Try the changes it will definitely work and plz accept the answer.

Comment: this is not working. Still having the null point exception I had last time

Answer (score 3):

Add in your servlet

```
request.setAttribute("rs",rs);

RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("your url");  
rd.forward(request, response);
```

on jsp page

```
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)request.getAttribute("rs");

<%while (rs.next()) {
    String item_id = rs.get(0);
    String name = rs.get(1);
    String unit_price = rs.get(2);
    String qty = rs.get(3);
    %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=item_id%></td>
      <td><%=name%></td>
      <td><%=unit_price%></td>
      <td><%=qty%></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake - sorry. I edited my code. You can forward your collection rather than whole resultset. And iterate over collection.

Comment: are u saying avoid array list? the what is getmethod